# Как правильно сверстать Html?

Tags: php, html, css

Добрый день! Есть шаблон!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По середине видно списко категорий. Я буду выводить списком категории из БД через цикл foreach. Выпадающее категории определенного размера, высота 500 px. Как правильно сверстать?

Comment: С помощью HTML+CSS попробуйте сверстать, как же ещё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если по простенькому можно и примерно так

```
$menu_array = getMenuItemsFromDataBase();

$items_per_column = 30; //количество элементов в колонке

$i = 0;

$html = '';

$last_element = count($menu_array) - 1;

foreach ($menu_array as $key => $value) {

    if($i == 0){
        $html .= '<ul>';
    }elseif($i == $items_per_column || $value == $last_element){
        $html .= '</ul>';

        $i = 0;
    }else{
        $html .= '<li>' . $value->title . '</li>';
    };

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: я так понял стиль к списку нужно применить display:inline?

Answer (score 2):

Семантически корректнее - вложенными ненумерованными списками. Для разбиения на колонки используйте column-count.
А вообще можно и дивами, как вам удобнее.

Comment: вот как дивами? после каждого прохода цикла проверять, какая высота div и если больше 500 то переносить?

Comment: @duddeniska на php будет сложно высоту верстки проверить:) если только на js.

Comment: у меня БД на MySql, поэтому надо как то подружиться php и html

Comment: Вы пытаетесь вынести логику вёрстки в backend. Не делайте этого. Хуже только вынесение бизнес-логики во frontend.

Comment: @AntonioK Тогда какое решение данной задачи? не ушто все категории писать вручную в HTML:?

Comment: Вам уже ответили - выводите контент HTML-списком, ограничиваете его высоту контейнером, разбиваете внутри на колонки.

Answer (score 2):

Если критична поддержка старых браузеров, то можно воспользоваться jQuery плагином [Сolumnizer jQuery Plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?